# Special smoothing

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, depth, smoothing

I have pictures like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reu92.png) (I've got it from depth map after some processing)

Every pixel of the image is some direction (of gradient of image)

I want to process these image so that sides of box from image become smooth and edges become more distinguishable. Also is important for me to save "major color" of every edge.
I know about bilateral filter, but i can't find good parameters for it

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1dZu.png) one of bilateral filter output. Nice left side, but right-front side still sharp and top side is over smoothed

Is there way out?

Comment: Have you check the result of an LoG (Laplaccian of gaussian Filter)?

Comment: No, i haven't. I will do it soon

Comment: @ogni42 is LoG this? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/laplace_operator/laplace_operator.html

Comment: it is the combination of the laplacial operator with the gaussian blur (as the program you've posted in the link does) This can be applied in one filter.

Comment: Can you advise me any LoG implementation over OpenCV? I can't find it :(

Comment: also simply applying gaussian blur after laplacian gives some result, but it still doesn't satisfy me. http://s21.postimg.org/4g76kdhfr/tmp2.png